# cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Tags: php, laravel-5, ssl, web-scraping

Estou tentando realizar um `WebScraping`, porem estou obtendo o seguinte erro como retorno:

> cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Minha controladora esta com o seguinte código:

```
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://esaj.tjsp.jus.br/cpopg/show.do?processo.codigo=XXXXXXXXX&processo.numero=XXXXXXXX');
$crawler->filter('h2 > a')->each(function ($node) {
    dd($node->text()."\n");
});
```

No meu `php.ini` já fiz a configuração do certificado porém para:

```
curl.cainfo = "D:\Trabalho\backendresolveaqui\cacert.pem"
openssl.cafile= "D:\Trabalho\backendresolveaqui\cacert.pem"
```

Porém não obtive sucesso, alguém saberia como resolver esse problema?

***Observação:*** Estou a usar a versão 5.8 do Laravel e PHP versão 7.3.5.